# Pylint resulting in RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration with latest package versions

Tags: python, pylint

Here are my package versions,

```
$ pylint --version
pylint 2.3.1
astroid 2.2.5
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 14 2019, 12:09:51) 
[GCC 8.3.0]
```

When I run

```
pylint {package_name}
```

I get a `RuntimeError` as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/protocols.py", line 492, in _infer_context_manager
    enter = next(inferred.igetattr("__enter__", context=context))
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pylint", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 20, in run_pylint
    Run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1628, in __init__
    linter.check(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 943, in check
    self._do_check(files_or_modules)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1075, in _do_check
    self.check_astroid_module(ast_node, walker, rawcheckers, tokencheckers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1158, in check_astroid_module
    walker.walk(ast_node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 1303, in walk
    self.walk(child)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 1300, in walk
    cb(astroid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylint/checkers/variables.py", line 1590, in visit_import
    module = next(_infer_name_module(node, parts[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/util.py", line 160, in limit_inference
    yield from islice(iterator, size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/context.py", line 113, in cache_generator
    for result in generator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 131, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 95, in wrapped
    res = next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/inference.py", line 240, in infer_import
    yield self.do_import_module(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/mixins.py", line 100, in do_import_module
    modname, level=level, relative_only=level and level >= 1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/scoped_nodes.py", line 619, in import_module
    return MANAGER.ast_from_module_name(absmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 171, in ast_from_module_name
    return self.ast_from_file(found_spec.location, modname, fallback=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 91, in ast_from_file
    return AstroidBuilder(self).file_build(filepath, modname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 136, in file_build
    return self._post_build(module, encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 153, in _post_build
    self.add_from_names_to_locals(from_node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 206, in add_from_names_to_locals
    imported = node.do_import_module()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/mixins.py", line 100, in do_import_module
    modname, level=level, relative_only=level and level >= 1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/scoped_nodes.py", line 619, in import_module
    return MANAGER.ast_from_module_name(absmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 171, in ast_from_module_name
    return self.ast_from_file(found_spec.location, modname, fallback=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 91, in ast_from_file
    return AstroidBuilder(self).file_build(filepath, modname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 136, in file_build
    return self._post_build(module, encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 156, in _post_build
    self.delayed_assattr(delayed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/builder.py", line 223, in delayed_assattr
    for inferred in node.expr.infer():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 141, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield from generator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 95, in wrapped
    res = next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/inference.py", line 279, in infer_attribute
    for owner in self.expr.infer(context):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/util.py", line 160, in limit_inference
    yield from islice(iterator, size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/context.py", line 113, in cache_generator
    for result in generator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 141, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield from generator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 95, in wrapped
    res = next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/bases.py", line 137, in _infer_stmts
    for inferred in stmt.infer(context=context):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/util.py", line 160, in limit_inference
    yield from islice(iterator, size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/context.py", line 113, in cache_generator
    for result in generator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 131, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 92, in wrapped
    generator = _func(node, context, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/inference.py", line 832, in infer_assign
    stmts = list(self.assigned_stmts(context=context))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/decorators.py", line 131, in raise_if_nothing_inferred
    yield next(generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/astroid/protocols.py", line 537, in with_assigned_stmts
    yield from _infer_context_manager(self, mgr, context)
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

From some search, it seems like this error should've been fixed with `Pylint 2.x`, however, I still get an error with the latest versions with `Python 3.7`. Any fixes?